# Resource not found on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, slick2d

**Resource not found on eclipse.**

I am creating a game using Slick2D, and for some reason it's say I don't have the image/spritesheet.. I tried looking around for others with similar issues, but it just doesn't work...

[Line of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSUGt.png)

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TT74d.png)

[The location of the spritesheet and the location of the classes needing to use it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5P2Xx.png)

Comment: You're referencing the file with a relative path. What do you think it is relative to? What is it actually relative to, and how will this eventually work in a jar file?